# Twilio : Response application link not working

Tags: php

I am unsing Twilio Rest Api for SMS functionality. My SMS is send sucessfully problem is when user response to SMS, I have to capture that response in my application and send confirmation email to user

I am unable to capture response from application URL.Please give me some idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code of what you done so far?

Comment: yes, My code is below .I have set URL in TwimL application as SMS URL : mywebsiteURL/replytosms and replytosms function like

Comment: I have set URL in TwimL application as SMS URL : mywebsiteURL/replytosms and replytosms function like                     function replytosms()
 {
  if(isset($_REQUEST['To']))
  $to = $_REQUEST['To'];
  $fromBody = trim($fromBody);   
  if(stristr($fromBody, 'yes') == TRUE || stristr($fromBody, 'y') || stristr($fromBody, 'Y'))
  {
     $response = 'YES';
  }
  else
  {
     $response = 'ERROR';
  }
  switch($response)
  {
    case 'YES':
   // send message
   break;
    case 'ERROR':
    default:break;
  }//switch 
 }//replysms

Answer (score 0):

The example app [here in PHP](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134267-Building-an-SMS-Keyword-Response-Application) shows how to build keyword response based upon the body of the incoming text message.

The important thing to note is to fetch the [`Body` request parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#synchronous) of the message which is simply:

```
/* Read the contents of the `'Body'` field of the Request. */ 

$body = $_REQUEST['Body'];
```

Instead of 'fromBody'.